# How to show output for MeteorJS application's Docker build process?

Tags: node.js, meteor, docker

I'm using Docker to build and run a MeteorJS app. Meteor uses Node to build the app and does that thing where instead of writing several lines of info to the console during the build it just overwrites the same line again each time it starts a new build process (with the \ | / spinner thing at the end).

This is a problem because it means that Docker doesn't show any output during the build process and (1) I can't diagnose problems when the build gets hung on a particular step, and (2) if the Meteor build takes too long then the Docker build times out.

Is there any way to show the output for the Meteor/Node build along with the rest of the output for the Docker build?

Comment: You can use --verbose, which gives you a little more output, but doesn't really address the problem

Comment: and what you get if you run `docker logs <container_id> ?

Comment: Is it too verbose to `strace docker build...`?

Comment: what command are you using to run the build step? Have you considered [piping stderr](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#/return-code) to a file?